# Algorithm to win in the roulette

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions

Suposse that you bet to one number in the roulette, the probability of hit is 1/37.

Use the binomial distribution for calculate the probabily of hit 
at least one time in k spins is:

$$1 - \binom{k}{0} *  (1/37)^0 * (1 - 1/37)^k $$

So

$$1 - (36/37)^k $$

I want win how minimum 10:

[The table with de content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwgAH.png)

¿Is correct?

If I bet 26 times in a row to the same number, the probability of winning would be 0.510, if I bet 100 0.934, then I only have to win once to recover what I lost and more.

Comment: I am not sure that this would be allowed.

Comment: And if it is allowed in my country?

Comment: I don't understand.  If, over $26$ trials,  you win once your net payout is $10$.  If you win zero times your net payout is $-26$, so your expectation is, of course, negative.

Comment: More broadly, each trial has negative expectation (clearly) so simply playing over and over again can not create a positive expectation.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwgAH.png

Comment: In the spins 27 I climb the bet to 2. This allows me to make martigala sustainable over time

Comment: I tried to see your picture, but could not read it.  You are still ignoring the fact that a series of losing bets cannot make a winning series.  You can have a high probability of winning, but do not confuse that with a positive expectation.  You will have a small probability of a large loss, which will exceed the expectation of the wins.

Answer (score 1):

No, this does not work. The probability your number is the winning one is $\frac{1}{37}\ \ ^1$ every try and the win is only 36 times your bet. You can understand that that green zero is your lose.$^2$

---

$^1$ this is the probablity with only one green "zero", of course if you are playing in an old fashioned casino with roulette allowed to carry the double zero the probability of winning is $\frac{1}{38}$

$^2$I don't want to discourage you, but trust me, if there would have been a way of winning at the roulette no man would still be working lol

Comment: you don't understand, see the picture

Comment: Okay, let's suppose for a second that math does not exist, your table finish at after 140 tries and suppose again for a second that you have tried your method but after 140 tries you still have not win (as you stated, there is the 2.2% this happens). After having spent more or less an hour of gambling (it means every 30 seconds a numer is given) and after having spent 1272 unit coins, you have no certainty of winning on the next try. Worse and worse, suppose you win on your 125th try. You have spent an hour and got only 1 unit coin.. It seems going to work is not such a bad idea lol

Comment: However, to be more serious, your approach looks like a Martigala, but again, you need too many unit coins and once you win, you only have won a unit approximation of the starting bet

Comment: Yes, it's a martingale sustainable in the time. correct, but.. In my country i can  press and stop the virtual roulette in 2 seconds

Comment: Okay but as I said every Martingale needs a huge amount of money and in most cases is the best way of losing big sums of money in a very few time. Be careful.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, but no series of losing bets can have a positive expectation.  It is quite possible to have a chance higher than $0.50$ to win, but that will be overbalanced by a small chance to lose a large amount.

If you bet $26$ times (whether the same number or not) you are correct that the chance to lose them all is about $0.490479$ and your chance to win at least one (and show a profit on the series) is about $0.509521$  If you lose them all you lose $26$ times your bet.  Your chance to win exactly once is about $0.3542347$ and you win $10$.  If you add up all the probable outcomes, your expectation is $-\frac {26}{37}\approx -0.7027$